# bsub command creates a new shell. Does not execute the following set of commands in a shell script. Is there a work around to it?

Tags: bash, shell, conda, hpc, lsf

I have the simple set of commands that I follow on HPC cluster for launching specific Interactive job and then Launch Jupyter notebook over it as follows. I tried to create script for the same set of commands. But after the first bsub command (which drop me into a new shell), remaining commands are not executed.

My script :

```
bsub -n 10 -W 4:00 -Is bash
&& 
conda activate env 
&& 
cd /lustre/scratch/user/ 
&& 
jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8850
```

after `bsub -n 10 -W 4:00 -Is bash` following set of commands are not executed. This command creates a new shell according to admin. Is there a work around for this ? One solution is that I can create a separate script for remaining 3 commands but It would be great to have them combined.

Comment: The way this is written, the bash command will be invoked, and then nothing else will happen until it exits cleanly. If you want to invoke those commands in the `bsub`'d environment, then you would run the bsub as: `bsub -n 10 -W 4:00 bash -c "conda activate env && cd /lustre/scratch/user && jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8850"`. This assumes they're the only commands you want to issue in the bsub environment.

Comment: Try `bash -l` (login mode). The `conda activate` function is defined in the user shell initialization script. Alternatively, use `conda run -n env --live-stream jupyter notebook...`.